# Calculate Pay using an Age range in excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I’m trying to put a excel sheet together for a local business
We are trying to find out a method to use an excel function to calculate pay based on age using age ranges , 
Ie  if pay age range is 18 - 21 pay would be $5.00 or if age is 25 and over pay would be $10.
Thank you

Comment: Use a lookup table and VLOOKUP against it. Have age ranges in left column and pay in right column. It will be much easier to update and maintain than amending formulas. Make sure the lookup table is an actual Excel table.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have name in column A and Age in column B, then you can use this formula to calculate the wages in column C. You can edit the age range as per your requirement.

=IF(AND(B2>=18,B2 <= 25),5,IF(B2>25,10,0))

Comment: But I also have the hours worked, the correct age band would have to be matched to persons age and then multiplied by their number of hours?

Comment: Shahin - please put all the information in the question. We cannot read your mind. Try to make sure the question is complete before posting rather than adding details later. [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have name in column A, Age in column B and No of hours in column C then you can use this formula to calculate the wages in column D. You can edit the age range as per your requirement. It would work.

=IF(AND(B2>=18,B2 <= 25),5*C2,IF(B2>25,10*C2,0))

Comment: Putting the fixed values in the formula like this is very prone to error when editing is needed - calling the rates from cells is better and vlookup on a table even better...